# Binary Search Tree Implementation error

Tags: python, search, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

In the following Binary Search Tree (initial) implementation, I am creating an object and trying to call the insert method to add a node. The output is erroneous, can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

**Code:**

```
class Node():
            def __init__(self,data):
            #attributes are: node data, left node data and right node data
                        self.data=data
                        self.left=None
                        self.right=None

            def print_nodes(self):
                        print(self.data)

            def insert(self,data):
                        if self.data:
                                    if data<self.data: #if the data passed into insert, is less the existing node
                                                if self.left is None: #if the left node is empty...
                                                            self.left=Node(data) #call the Node with t he data given - inserted into left node
                                                else:
                                                            self.left.insert(data)
                                    elif data>self.data:
                                                 if self.right is None:
                                                             self.right=Node(data)
                                                 else:
                                                             self.right.insert(data)
                                    else:
                                                            self.data=data


root=Node(8)
root=Node(3)
root.print_nodes()
root.insert(10)
root.insert(1)
root.print_nodes()
```

**OUTPUT (LOGIC ERROR)**
I was hoping for it to print out all the nodes in the binary tree, e.g. 8 and then 3, but it doesn't. Is there a way to do this efficiently/simply?

```
    3
    3
    >>>
```

**Also note that just calling this, does work and prints 8**

```
root=Node(8)
root.print_nodes()
```

**But**

```
root=Node(8)
root.Insert(3)
root.print_nodes()
```

**has an output of:**

```
8
8
```

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried to, based on a helpful comment below, add a more advanced print method (print_tree). It now prints out more......but the output is still baffling.

**Updated Code with print_tree method updated**

```
class Node():
            def __init__(self,data):
            #attributes are: node data, left node data and right node data
                        self.data=data
                        self.left=None
                        self.right=None

            def print_tree(self):
                        if self.left:
                                    self.left.print_tree()
                        print(self.data)
                        if self.right:
                                    self.right.print_tree()


            def insert(self, data):
                    if self.data:
                        if data < self.data:
                            if self.left is None:
                                self.left = Node(data)
                            else:
                                self.left.insert(data)
                        elif data > self.data:
                            if self.right is None:
                                self.right = Node(data)
                            else:
                                self.right.insert(data)
                    else:
                        self.data = data           



root=Node(8)
root.print_tree()
root.insert(3)
root.print_tree()
root.insert(5)
root.print_tree()
```

**Output:**

```
8
3
8
3
5
8
>>>
```

Comment: `root=Node(8); root=Node(3); root.print_nodes()`

You do not insert 3 into the tree, you create a new tree and forget about the 8.

Comment: Also, `print_nodes` does not work recursively, it will only ever print the value of one node.

Comment: Is there a way I can print the value of all the nodes ...

Comment: You seem to have solved your problem.